# Hide button after click two times or more on as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am new on as3. 
i want to ask how to hide button after click two times or more on as3.
the code below i got from code snippets, but the button hide after one click.

```
 BTNhint.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide);

function fl_ClickToHide(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    BTNhint.visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to count the button clicks and then after two clicks you can hide your button :

```
var click_counter:int = 0;

BTNhint.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide); 
function fl_ClickToHide(event:MouseEvent):void
{   
    click_counter ++; // you can write it : click_counter = click_counter + 1;

    if(click_counter >= 2){   // you can write it : if(click_counter > 1)
        BTNhint.visible = false;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `constant` (LIM) to determine how many times your button must be clicked, compare it to a `variable` (c)  that is counting your clicks, and use your MouseEvent's `target property` to target your button itself when you want it to disappear:

```
var c:int = 0;
const LIM:int = 2;

BTNhint.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hideMe);

function hideMe(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(++c >= LIM) event.target.visible = false;            
}
```